# Difference between Autofac IIndex<,> and a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

What exactly is the difference between `IIndex<,>` and a simple C# `Dictionary`? Are they both equal and is `IIndex<,>` the "Autofac Dictionary"?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a very good explanation about `IIndex<K, V>` [here](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/08/the-iindexkv-relationship-type/). As mentioned at the end of this article, it's more similar to .NET `ILookup<K, V>`, than `IDictionary<K, V>`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Autofac source code you can see in the source that [`IIndex`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/36b69bffbdd96cfe8d7a56a62b16f518dd72f590/src/Autofac/Features/Indexed/IIndex.cs) is just a simple interface which is implemented in the concrete class [`KeyedServiceIndex`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/36b69bffbdd96cfe8d7a56a62b16f518dd72f590/src/Autofac/Features/Indexed/KeyedServiceIndex.cs). It is not a dictionary at all and shouldn't be confused with one.

The Autofac documentation explains how to use it [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html?highlight=iindex).

Comment: But it is used with the same syntax and for the same purpose isn't it?

Comment: No, what makes you think that? Other than it's an interface for a keyed storage, it's nothing like a dictionary.